# Connecting probabilities with labels in scikit-learn

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn

I'm training `scikit-learn`'s `neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier` model object to predict a multi-class classification problem.  I've already predicted the most likely class, but now I want to extract the second most likely class predicted using the `predict_proba` function.  However, the output of the function just gives a raw numpy array, which is supposed to be sorted lexicographically.  However, when I eyeball the data to see if the probabilities are in alphabetical order, but it does not seem to be.

```
from sklearn import neighbors
knn_classifier  = neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors = NUM_NEIGHBORS, weights = 'distance', metric ='haversine' )
knn_classifier.fit(knn_data, response)

unique_levels =  response.unique()
unique_levels.sort()
print unique_levels
    ['Canada' 'DCarea' 'NYarea' 'bostonArea' 'caribbean' 'eastAsia' 'florida'
     'hawaii' 'italy' 'midwest' 'nevada' 'newEngland' 'northernEurope'
     'northern_california' 'northern_france' 'notFound' 'otherSouthernEurope'
     'pacificNW' 'pennArea' 'south' 'southAmerica' 'southeastAsiaAus'
     'southern_california' 'spain' 'texas' 'unitedKingdom' 'west']

knn_preds = knn_classifier.predict(knn_data)
knn_probs = knn_classifier.predict_proba(knn_data)

knn_preds[0:10]
    array(['DCarea', 'NYarea', 'DCarea', 'Canada', 'midwest', 'unitedKingdom',
           'midwest', 'NYarea', 'NYarea', 'south'], dtype=object)

knn_probs[0]
    array([ 0.    ,  0.0667,  0.2667,  0.0333,  0.1   ,  0.    ,  0.    ,
            0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0667,  0.1   ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0667,
            0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0333,  0.    ,  0.1   ,  0.    ,
            0.    ,  0.1333,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.    ,  0.0333])

knn_probs[1]
    array([ 0.   ,  0.   ,  0.25 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,
            0.   ,  0.125,  0.125,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.25 ,  0.   ,  0.   ,
            0.   ,  0.125,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ,  0.125,  0.   ,
            0.   ,  0.   ,  0.   ])
```

If the probabilities were sorted lexicographically, I would expect the second key in `knn_probs[0]` to have the highest probability, since `'DCarea'` was the winning class, and it comes second lexicographically (per above).  However, the largest value is the *third* item in the list. What gives?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I presume you are using Pandas; have you tried bypassing Pandas and using only numpy arrays and Python lists?

Comment: I suggest to move this question to stats or data science.

Answer (score 3):

I believe the probability order follows the order of the extracted labels in `knn_classifier.classes_`. You can `zip` the `classes_` and predict probability vectors together, sort and take the second one.

`classes_ = np.array(['a','b','c'])
prob_vec = np.array([0.6, 0, 0.4])
sec_class, sec_prob = list(sorted(zip(classes_, prob_vec), key=lambda k: -k[1]))[1]`

Comment: Is it only me or is the documentation of [predict_proba](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html#sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.predict_proba) just dead wrong when saying "Classes are ordered by lexicographic order"?